# prevent output of data if array not found

Tags: php

I have this piece of code which works well if the `['extensions']` array exists.. but if the array does not exist then it returns errors. How can I fix this code to not return anything if the extensions array does not exist?

-[UPDATE-

Sorry i had previously inserted the wrong code.. here is the proper code i need checked.

```
        $oid = array('id-ce-subjectAltName');
        $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
             if(array_key_exists('extensions', $cert['tbsCertificate']) &&
                in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]['extnId'], $oid)) {
                $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]['extnId'];
                echo "\n",'<b>[SANs]</b>',"\n","\n";
            }
        }
```

I get this warning when `['extensions']` does not exist - I would like to prevent any warnings from being generated.

> Notice:  Undefined index: extensions in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\certdecode\certdecode.php on line 142

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: what is line 142? you can still suppress this (as long as you know and you're sure that you want to suppress that) by using error_reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Please provide the output of `print_r($cert['tbsCertificate']);` ...

Answer (score 0):

AFTER UPDATE:

How is the structure of the array?

You count the number of items in $cert['tbsCertificate'],
but in your loop, your $i is for the number of items in $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'].

So maybe you try to do something like this?:

```
    $oid = array('id-ce-subjectAltName');
    if (array_key_exists('extensions', $cert['tbsCertificate']) &&
        is_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'])
    ) {
        $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if (in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]['extnId'], $oid)) {
                    $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$i]['extnId'];
                    echo "\n", '<b>[SANs]</b>', "\n", "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry i had the wrong code in my post - i just updated it, please check again?

Answer (score 0):

okay, seems to work by adding an isset() at the start of the code:

`if(isset($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'])) {`

thanks guys!